# How to use rep_slice_sample() to randomly sample within groups of varying observation number

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, resampling

I am building confidence intervals for groups with bootstrapped values and I'm having trouble creating multiple re-sampled datasets from which to build my confidence intervals.

Using the `palmerpenguins` library as an example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(infer)
library(palmerpenguins)
```

There are 344 total observations and each species has a different number of observations:

```
nrow(penguins)
[1] 344

penguins %>% group_by(species) %>% count()

# A tibble: 3 × 2
# Groups:   species [3]
  species       n
  <fct>     <int>
1 Adelie      152
2 Chinstrap    68
3 Gentoo      124
```

I want to be able to group by the species, and for each species pull multiple samples while using the original number of observations per each group.

```
set.seed(100)

slices <- penguins2 %>% 
    group_by(species) %>% 
    rep_slice_sample(prop = 1, replace = TRUE, reps = 10)
```

That should give me `344 * 10 = 3440` lines in the full new data set. This is true, but when you look at the data you can see that each replicate has a different number of observations. For all of the Adelie, n per sample should be 152, chinstrap should be 68, and Gentoo should be 124. Instead we find this:

```
slices %>% group_by(species, replicate) %>% count()

# A tibble: 30 × 3
# Groups:   species, replicate [30]
   species replicate     n
   <fct>       <int> <int>
 1 Adelie          1   148
 2 Adelie          2   147
 3 Adelie          3   148
 4 Adelie          4   151
 5 Adelie          5   138
 6 Adelie          6   157
 7 Adelie          7   161
 8 Adelie          8   157
 9 Adelie          9   151
10 Adelie         10   138
# ℹ 20 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

What am I missing?

Comment: based on this request and the conversations thereafter (https://github.com/tidymodels/infer/issues/197) , I'm left to assume this isn't a part of this library yet. I have moved on to find the solution with other tools using this blog post as reference: https://www.painblogr.org/2017-10-18-purrring-through-bootstraps.html

Answer (score 3):

I think it's easier to apply `rep_slice_sample` once you have split the data on species rather than within groups. There may be some nifty tidyverse way to do it without splitting but I think the code below does what you intend.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(infer)
library(palmerpenguins)


penguins |> 
  group_by(species) |> 
  group_split() |> 
  map(~ rep_slice_sample(.x, prop = 1, replace = TRUE, reps = 10)) |> 
  bind_rows()
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option with `slice_sample`:

(`penguins %>% slice_sample(prop = 10, replace = TRUE, by = species)` also works (i.e. with `prop = 10`), but doesn't provide the replicate number.)

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)

set.seed(100)

slices <- map(1:10, \(x)(
  penguins %>% 
    slice_sample(prop = 1, replace = TRUE, by = species) |> 
    mutate(replicate = x)
)) |> 
  bind_rows()

slices %>% count(species, replicate)
#> # A tibble: 30 × 3
#>    species replicate     n
#>    <fct>       <int> <int>
#>  1 Adelie          1   152
#>  2 Adelie          2   152
#>  3 Adelie          3   152
#>  4 Adelie          4   152
#>  5 Adelie          5   152
#>  6 Adelie          6   152
#>  7 Adelie          7   152
#>  8 Adelie          8   152
#>  9 Adelie          9   152
#> 10 Adelie         10   152
#> # ℹ 20 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-17 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thanks Carl, I had stumbled across the lack of replicate number at one point and I like how you fixed that here.